# Some MP4 files play sound only on Chrome, IE(edge) and FireFox, do I have to change videos codec?

Tags: html, video

I have some MP4 files where sound is played but video is not shown, while all the other mp4 files are playing just fine. I used PHP to echo video from the database, and obviously html to show it.

The videos that show sound only, I have recorded using my phone while the ones that work I used my desktop. They both have MP4 extension. I believe its got something to do with the codec ?

Do I have to specify or change current videos codec before displaying it, or uploading it ?

```
<video  style="
          width: auto ;
           max-width: 100% ;
           height: auto ;
           width: 600px;
           height: 560px;
           object-fit: fill;" 

    class="video-item" controls = "controls" loop>
    <source   src="cvs/<?php echo $articles['data']?>" type="video/mp4">
```

Comment: maybe the width and height for the video is not enough? idk, a few screenshots could help.

Comment: I did try changing css but it does not seem to have any effect

Comment: What does _"using my phone"_ mean **exactly** (what brand / OS)? If it was an iPhone then you might have recorded video with **H.265** picture format (codec) which is only supported on Safari browser. You need H.264 video inside your MP4 for wider compatibility.

Comment: It's an android, Samsung A40 to be precise. I wouldn't ask a question if it was that obvious ( if it was an iPhone ) haha.

Comment: I've tried using different phones Samsung A20 and Samsung A52s and it works with them. I recorded using these phones and upload the video, showing successfully. It seems to be related to my A40 only. I'm still curious to why this is.

Comment: _"It's an android, Samsung A40 to be precise"_ after checking the A40 records H.265 just like iPhone. Your correct solution was turn off the H265/HEVC/HEIF encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out samsung has a setting, option called "HEVC" which lowers the videos file size but makes it impossible to upload and display it online. I turned it off and now it works just fine.

Comment: HEIF and HEVC are two sides of the same H.265 picture format (**High Efficiency** where the following is **IF** for Image Format or is **VC** for Video Codec). HEIF is just an H265 video keyframe as still image, so how odd that an entire video file is in HEIF format. I think A40 just calls it HEIF but after checking myself I see most spec sheets say the A40 supports H.265 video.

Comment: You are right, i have corrected the answer. HEVC stands for the Video Codec.